# Ошибка в типах данных TypeScript у React компонента

Tags: typescript

Я сделал вот такой компонент.
У меня горит ошибка при наведении на название компонента.

Вот мой код:

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import './index.scss'
import 'moment/locale/ru'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'
import { ArrowIcon } from '../Icons/ArrowIcon'

interface IPrevButton {
    selectedDate: Date
    calendarHandlePrevClick: () => void
}

export const PrevButton: FC<IPrevButton> = ({
    selectedDate,
    calendarHandlePrevClick,
}) => {
    const month = selectedDate.getMonth()
    const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth()
    return month !== currentMonth ? (
        <span
            className='date-picker-root__left-arrow'
            onClick={calendarHandlePrevClick}
        >
            <ArrowIcon />
        </span>
    ) : (
        ''
    )
}

export default PrevButton
```

А вот ошибка

```
Тип "({ selectedDate, calendarHandlePrevClick, }: PropsWithChildren<IPrevButton>) => Element | """ не может быть назначен для типа "FC<IPrevButton>".
  Тип "Element | """ не может быть назначен для типа "ReactElement<any, any> | null".
    Тип """" не может быть назначен для типа "ReactElement<any, any> | null".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Тип """" не может быть назначен для типа "ReactElement<any, any> | null".

Вроде ж понятно написано.

> ```
> ) : (
>     ''
> )
> ```

```
) : null
```